# Regexp lazy quantifier

Tags: regex

I have a sentence like this

```
a something* q b c w
```

and i have to match *a* and *q* together like

```
(id_1: a, id_2: q)
```

*b* alone like

```
(id_1: b)
```

and *c* and *w* together like 
    (id_1:c id_2:w)

I tried to use this regexp

```
(?:\b(?P<id_1>a|b|c)\b(?:.*?)(?P<id_2>q|w)?\b)
```

Because of the lazy operator **.*?** the regexp matches only the first part of the sentence, matching only

```
(id_1: a, id_1: b, id_1: c)
```

[Live Example](https://regex101.com/r/aT5cG9/2)

If we use a greedy operator such that the expression becomes

```
(?:\b(?P<id_1>a|b|c)\b(?:.*)(?P<id_2>q|w)?\b)
```

[Live Example](https://regex101.com/r/bE0eT4/3)

It matches

```
(id_1: a)
```

an everything after is matched as **.*** .

If the second part is mandatory (with lazy on **.*** ):

```
(?:\b(?P<id_1>a|b|c)\b(?:.*?)(?P<id_2>q|w)\b)
```

[Live Example](https://regex101.com/r/tW6hZ2/2)

it matches sentences like

```
(id_1: a, id_2: q);(id_1: b, id_2: w)
```

as expected.

It is possible to use a regular expression that "prefers" matching the whole sentence (including the optional part) or that matches only the first part **ONLY** if the optional one is missing.

**EDIT:**
Sorry the regexes provided had some errors in them.

The last regex is:

```
(?:\b(?P<id_1>a|b|c)\b(?:.*?)(?P<id_2>q|w)\b)
```

and it requires both group to be mandatory. It matches "a something* w" but it doesn't match "a something*" or just "a". I need to match "a something* w" as well as "a" and "a w" and get the matching group respectively:

```
(id_1: a , id_2: w) ; (id_1: a, id_2: none) ; (id_1:a , id_2: w)
```

I think that the regex required is:

```
(?:\b(?P<id_1>a|b|c)\b(?:.*?)(?P<id_2>q|w)?\b)
```

but in the sentence "a something* w" it just matches "a" (due to the lazy operator on .*).

I have also updated all the live examples.

Comment: Isn't your last regex matching strings the way you need? I removed `b c w` and there is a match. Could you use 1 example to describe what you need to match in it and which regex is the closest, what is missing?

Comment: Hi @stribizhev, thanks for your help. I edited the question because there was some errors in the expressions. I also provided an example in the EDIT section.

Comment: Like [`\b(?P<id_1>a|b|c)\b(?:(?!\b(?:q|w)\b).)*(?P<id_2>q|w|)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/vU4wZ0/4)? Or perhaps, [`\b(?P<id_1>a|b|c)\b(?:(?!\b(?:q|w)\b).)*(?P<id_2>q|w)?\b`](https://regex101.com/r/iP2pZ5/1)?

Comment: Is the language Python or PHP?

Comment: @stribizhev the second one is very similar to what I need. With a little modification works perfectly:
[\b(?P<id_1>a|b|c)\b(?:(?!\b(?:q|w|a|b|c)\b).)*(?P<id_2>q|w)?\b](https://regex101.com/r/iP2pZ5/2)

I worried about its efficiency if I have several words in or. Is there any other way to do the same without repeating 2 times both the or list?

ty anyway for your help

ps. it's python

Comment: Are `a`, `b`, etc. variables that are actually more than 1 symbol in length? There can be a trick using an unroll-the-loop regex, but to use it, you need to know exact variable contents. And the regex will be unreadable.

Comment: yes, they are variable that represent word

Comment: That means you need to manually enhance such a regex. Perhaps, you should look for some non-regex based solution if the one suggested by me is not efficient enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lazy dot matching is a problem root cause since it requires a trailing boundary to exist.

If you need to match some text that is not specific text, you can use 2 things: either a tempered greedy token or an [unroll-the-loop](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop) based regex.

If you have variables you can use a [tempered greedy token](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) and make the second capture group optional with `?` quantifier:

```
\b(?P<id_1>a|b|c)\b(?:(?!\b(?:a|b|c|q|w)\b).)*(?P<id_2>q|w)?\b
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^             ^
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iC1rZ1/2)

Comment: In case you have multiline input, do not forget to use `re.DOTALL`/`re.S` flag so that `.` could match a newline.